# In RxJava what is the difference between Emitter interface and Observer interface ? both have same methods

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive, rx-java3

In RxJava what is the difference between Emitter interface and Observer interface ? both have same methods

```
public interface Emitter<@NonNull T> {

    /**
     * Signal a normal value.
     * @param value the value to signal, not {@code null}
     */
    void onNext(@NonNull T value);

    /**
     * Signal a {@link Throwable} exception.
     * @param error the {@code Throwable} to signal, not {@code null}
     */
    void onError(@NonNull Throwable error);

    /**
     * Signal a completion.
     */
    void onComplete();
}


public interface Observer<@NonNull T> {

    /**
     * Provides the {@link Observer} with the means of cancelling (disposing) the
     * connection (channel) with the {@link Observable} in both
     * synchronous (from within {@link #onNext(Object)}) and asynchronous manner.
     * @param d the {@link Disposable} instance whose {@link Disposable#dispose()} can
     * be called anytime to cancel the connection
     * @since 2.0
     */
    void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d);

    /**
     * Provides the {@link Observer} with a new item to observe.
     * <p>
     * The {@link Observable} may call this method 0 or more times.
     * <p>
     * The {@code Observable} will not call this method again after it calls either {@link #onComplete} or
     * {@link #onError}.
     *
     * @param t
     *          the item emitted by the Observable
     */
    void onNext(@NonNull T t);

    /**
     * Notifies the {@link Observer} that the {@link Observable} has experienced an error condition.
     * <p>
     * If the {@code Observable} calls this method, it will not thereafter call {@link #onNext} or
     * {@link #onComplete}.
     *
     * @param e
     *          the exception encountered by the Observable
     */
    void onError(@NonNull Throwable e);

    /**
     * Notifies the {@link Observer} that the {@link Observable} has finished sending push-based notifications.
     * <p>
     * The {@code Observable} will not call this method if it calls {@link #onError}.
     */
    void onComplete();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> both have same methods

No. `Observer.onSubscribe` is deliberately not present in `Emitter`.

`Emitter` is an interface to allow a callback to signal one item, one error or complete. It is used in the [`generate`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#generate-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-) operator to produce the next signal.

Since `generate` handles cancellation inbetween invocation of the callback, there is no reason or means to call `onSubscribe` of an `Observer`, thus to avoid confusion and to have a clean minimal API, the `Observer` interface cannot be used and a dedicated interface, `Emitter`, has been added instead.

Answer (score 0):

An `Emitter` calls its `onNext` when there is something new. An `Observer` expects its `onNext` to be called when there is something new.

The `Emitter` knows about events and can expose them by calling its `onNext`. An `Observer` wants to be told about events and will learn about them when its `onNext` is called.